# returning zero when converting string to integer in php

Tags: php, casting

when I want to convert a numeric string variable into integer in php, the return value is zero. I used all ways to convert it! such as:(int), (integer), intval(), settype(), eval(), etc. all of them return zero!

`var_dump($myVariable)` prints the following:

```
string(4) "۲۹"
```

Comment: Can you post the string you are casting/converting?

Comment: it is return value of a function this is its link: http://jdf.scr.ir/download/dl.php
the variable I used is this:
$month_length = jdate('t');
I want to convert $month_length to integer and use it as index of a for loop

Comment: This does not help at all. Please do a `var_dump($month_length)` and post the result in your question

Comment: string(4) "۲۹" 
oh! I think this is because the return value is UTF8 ! how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it! before converting string to integer, I should convert arabic number to english using this function:

```
function convert($string) {
$persian = array('۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹');
$num = range(0, 9);
return str_replace($persian, $num, $string);
}
```

now, I can convert it!
thanks from kingkero.

Answer (score 9):

Other common error is trying to cast a string variable that contains numbers but starts with zero, i.e.:

```
string(5) " 358"
```

To solve this, I used a filter_var sanitizing number INT doing this:

```
$myVariable = filter_var($myVariable, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```